# Read/write-through in C# and Node.js

Tags: c#, ignite

How can I use read/write-through with C# and Node.js clients? Appreciate it if you could provide code samples.

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/external-storage#read-through-and-write-through

Answer (score 1):

C# (Ignite.NET): check the [cache store example](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/dotnet/examples/Thick/Cache/Store/Program.cs) and the [cache store implementation](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/dotnet/examples/Shared/Cache/EmployeeStore.cs).

To use read/write through:

- Implement `ICacheStore<K, V>`
- Update configuration:

  ```
            new CacheConfiguration
            {
                Name = CacheName,
                ReadThrough = true,
                WriteThrough = true,
                CacheStoreFactory = new MyStoreFactory()
            }
  ```

---

For thin clients (Node.js, C#, etc) there is nothing to do on the client side. Cache store should be implemented and configured on the server side - in Java or C#.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code Pavel! I understand. However, I'm surprised about C#. I thought the server-side is completely Java based. Are there any documentation or resources about the C# based serverside implementation?

Comment: Server-side is Java based, that's true. However, you can start .NET server nodes where CLR and JVM run in the same process, which allows for .NET/C# implementations of Compute jobs, query filters, cache stores, etc. Java delegates those things to .NET. See https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/net-specific/net-standalone-nodes, https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/net-specific/net-platform-interoperability

Comment: This is really cool. Thank you Pavel!